# Equivalent of SAML's back-channel Single Log-out in OIDC?

Tags: openid-connect

For OpenID Connect, is there an equivalent of SAML's SOAP-based single log-out protocol to enable an identity provider the ability to terminate remote sessions in an RP application?  This is a necessary component for several security requirements in certain enterprise environments including but not limited to:

- Enact limits on the number of concurrent sessions by terminating previous sessions.
- Ability for administrators to terminate specific sessions or all sessions for a given user.
- Ability to terminate sessions upon other trigger events, such as a password change.

Answer (score 0):

That is not part of the core OpenID Connect specification (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), nor the implementers draft extension for Session Management (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) which btw. does include "JavaScript postMessage based" frontchannel logout.

There is however work-in-progress on a separate logout extension to OpenID Connect that may standardize backchannel logout, see: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-logout-1_0.html, esp. chapter 2 http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-logout-1_0.html. That is in early draft mode only so far.